# Can't display correct bipartite graph with networkx

Tags: networkx, bipartite

I am trying to draw a bipartite graph with nodes on left colored differently than nodes on right. I am using networkx and matplotlib to do so. 
Given a bipartite graph [(1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4)], I wish to display [1,2,3], colored blue on one side and [4,5] colored aqua on other side, with the edges (1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4) in between. 
The following is my code.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_bipartite(edges_list):
    left,right = set(),set()
    for s,t in edges_list:
        right.add(s)
        left.add(t)

    B = nx.Graph()
    B.add_nodes_from(list(right), bipartite=0)
    B.add_nodes_from(list(left), bipartite=1)
    B.add_edges_from(edges_list)

    nodecolor = []
    for node in B.nodes():
        a = 'blue' if node in list(right) else 'aqua'
        nodecolor.append(a)

    l,r = nx.bipartite.sets(B)
    pos = {}
    pos.update((node, (1, index)) for index, node in enumerate(l))
    pos.update((node, (2, index)) for index, node in enumerate(r))

    nx.draw(B, pos=pos,with_labels = True,node_color=nodecolor)
    plt.show()
draw_bipartite([(1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4)])
```

In output, the group [1,2,3] does not remain on left side, how do I keep it left side, as well as colored blue?
[image: My output graph]

Comment: please find the output of my code attached in the link "My output graph"

Comment: By the way, `node in list(right)` is very inefficient.  `node in right` is much better

Answer (score 0):

**update**
Looking at your code again, I see that only the color is determined by what you call `left` and `right`.  The positions are determined according to what you call `l` and `r`.  You have a bug in how you handle `left` and `right` and in how you handle `l` and `r`, so I'm addressing each of these separately.

So let's look at the **color first**: when you define `left` and `right` there is an error conceptually.

You are putting node 3 on both the left and the right.  Your edge `(1,3)` puts 3 on the left while `(3,4)` puts it on the right.  So the color that node 3 ends up with is `'blue'` because you've put it in `right`.  Since 4 was not put in `right`, it ends up `'aqua'`.   Note, it's confusing that what's on the left of a tuple ends up in `right` and you tell it to color `right` with blue, while saying in your explanation of the error that you want the *left* of your plot to be blue.  You should make this all consistent as it's going to be difficult to avoid making more errors in the future.

Now let's look at **node positions**: why `[1,2,3]` does not end up on the left.  You've defined `l` and `r` rather than taking the `left` and `right` you defined earlier (I don't think this was a good idea - use just one definition, or else you're just making it harder to hunt down bugs).  You've used `l,r = nx.bipartite.sets(B)` There are a few issues here.  First, the nodes 2 and 5 could end up on either side.  It's an arbitrary choice that is determined by the unpredictable order in which python loops through keys in a dict.  So you got lucky that `2` ended up in `l`.  Similarly, node `1` could have easily ended up in `r`.

The expectation that `3` would end up on the same side as `1` is hopeless - the networkx algorithm `bipartite.sets` separates nodes based on whether they share edges or not.  Since the edge `(1,3)` is in your graph, they will not end up on the same side.  If you had used your previously defined `left` and `right`, then `1` would have been on the right, and `3` would have ended up on either the left or the right, depending on the order of your two `pos.update` commands because it is in both `left` and `right`.